# Advanced usage of jpegoptim

Tags: unix, cron, jpegoptim

I am currently running the below jpegoptim command via cron to have jpegoptim look for jpg files to compress.

> find /home/public_html/public/uploads -name '*.jpg' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 jpegoptim -o -p --size=300k --strip-all

This works, but is there a way to include .jpeg, .JPG, and .JPEG without having to run the same command multiple times? Also, is it okay to run every hour, or would this keep compressing the same files eventually reducing the quality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match all of `*.jpg`, `*.JPG`, `*.jpeg`, `*.JPEG` by using two case-insensitive name matches.

```
find /home/public_html/public/uploads \
    '(' -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' ')' -type f -print0 \
| xargs -0 jpegoptim -o -p --size=300k --strip-all
```

You can keep a separate timestamp to avoid reprocessing the same files, for example

```
find /home/public_html/public/uploads \
    -newer .STAMP '(' -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.jpeg' ')' -type f -print0 \
| xargs -0 jpegoptim -o -p --size=300k --strip-all
touch .STAMP
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense here. Thank you.